# Adding items by setting a condition VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the bellow list:
[image]

I want to add items in columns C, E, G, I ... till the last column.
The idea is to look for the numbers on the first row in columns C, E, G ..., we select that number from a combobox (Combobox_Num) we look for it in the row 1 when we find it we add the data on the right column.
For example if a choose 001 from my combobox, the data should be added on the last row of column C, then I have to add the date aswell on the next column (column D for this example).
I've written this piece of code but it's do nothing, where is my mistake ?
Thank you

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Me.ComboBox_Lame.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Veuillez choisir une lame")
Else
'Nom_Lame = Me.ComboBox_Lame.Value
Num_Lame = Me.ComboBox_Num.Value

Dim ws_verifM1 As Worksheet
Set ws_verifM1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Verif_M1")
fin_liste = ws_verifM1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'fin_col = ws_verifM1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim Plage As Range
Set Plage = ws_verifM1.Rows(1)

Set Trouve = Plage.Cells.Find(what:=Num_Lame)
If Trouve Is Nothing Then
Else
    ws_verifM1.Cells(1, Trouve.Column).Value = Num_Lame
    
    ws_verifM1.Cells(Trouve.Rows, 3) = Me.ComboBox_Lame.Value & Me.ComboBox_Operation.Value
    ws_verifM1.Cells(Trouve.Rows, 4) = Me.TextBox_Date.Value
End If
End If
Unload Me
End Sub
```

the userform :

[image]

Comment: Could you try the following:

ws_verifM1.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 3) = Me.ComboBox_Lame.Value & Me.ComboBox_Operation.Value

ws_verifM1.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 4) = Me.TextBox_Date.Value

Comment: well it's not possible to have two equalities on the same line

Comment: Those are two lines of code. It should have a line break(carriage return) but this comment form does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot express my suggested code clearly in comment box (it does not display carriage return), I will just type it here:

```
ws_verifM1.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 3) = Me.ComboBox_Lame.Value & Me.ComboBox_Operation.Value 

ws_verifM1.Cells(fin_liste + 1, 4) = Me.TextBox_Date.Value
```

Please tell if I have understood your intention.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late replay, well  I've already try the 2 lines you have suggested but it's not working.